# Docker - is it necessary to push images to remote server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have successfully built some Docker images:[image]

Now I would like to start my microservices by `docker-compose`, unfortunatelly I am unable to pull those images i.e. `repository callista/discovery-server not found: does not exist or no pull access` I solved this error by logging into my DockerHub account and pushining those images to remote server. But it seems to me like a little overkill to send such larges images (which are likely to change pretty soon) over the Internet over and over again twice (push&pull).

Is it possible to configure Docker to install those images locally and not to pull from remote server?

I  use Docker 1.8 and work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to run this images in a server different from the one you build then?

If you need you have some alternatives:

- As @engineer-dollery said, you can run a registry into your network, than you would not need to send it over the internet, only in your network. Docs: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/
- You could use the `docker save` and `docker import` to move then around too. Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

But if the server you run the images is the same you build then...

...than you could just add the tag `image` to your `docker-compose` services, and do a `docker-compose build`, as @lauri said, but with the `image` `docker-compose` will create a image with that name after the build, and then you could do `docker run` using than. Or do a `docker-compose up --build` so it will always build than again if something changes into the `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

If you define `build` option in docker-compose.yml, you should be able to build images locally with Docker Compose and then it uses those images without pulling. By default Docker Compose builds images if they are not found locally. If you want to rebuild images just add `--build` option docker-compose up command `docker-compose up --build`

Docker Compose build reference:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build